# Implementing the Fragments inside ViewPager along with tab Strip

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am implementing the **fragment view inside the viewpager**.The situation is i have multiple tabs on click of which the fragments loads the data from web. 
Now Let suppose i have 5 tabs with all tabs assigned different forms for which the details filled after calling the Web Service. 
Now, the problem is, **on first fragment, the data loads using asynctask, and now when i swipe/click on tab for next fragment, the same async task loads again.**

Below is my code:

**view_pager_client.xml**

```
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**ViewPagerFragment.java**

```
public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {
    View view;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;
    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;


@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_client, container,false);
    initViews();
    return view;
    }



private void initViews() {

        ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager)view. findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
        adapterViewPager = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager());
        vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
        tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip)view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));
        tabs.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.White));
         tabs.setViewPager(vpPager);
         tabs.notifyDataSetChanged();

        vpPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            // This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                tabs.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            // This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                    int positionOffsetPixels) {
                // Code goes here 
//              tabs.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                // Code goes here
                tabs.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }
```

**FragmentPagerAdapter.java**

```
// Returns the fragment to display for that page
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0: 
                return new ProfileSummary();
            case 1: 
                return new ContactList();
            case 2: 
                return new ProfileSummary();
            default:
                return new ProfileSummary();
            }
        }
```

Now in Profile Summary and for contact list i am loading data from Web. The task which executes for profile summary, also executes for contact list.

Please help me in resolving the query.

Comment: what is your fragment code?

Comment: @mmlooloo for now i am just printing a sample text in my logcat using Log.e("fragment","name"); in my oncreateView()